# How to estimate gas of a receive method() in truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle, transactions, gas-estimate, receive

I know that if my contract has a name() method. I can go to the **truffle console** and try

> contractInstance.name.estimateGas()

and this will give the estimate gas for that method.

but what if have a receive method inside my contract to take ether:

```
receive() external payable {
}
```

and I wanna know it's gas. Then what is the correct syntax?

I've tried:

> contractInstance.estimateGas()

as I thought as receive is the default function for ether payment. But didn't work.

> contractInstance.receive.estimateGas()

this doesn't work either.

can I get some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem there's a specific call to estimateGas of the fallback/receive function. You could use web3's `estimateGas`

```
web3.eth.estimateGas({
  to: contract.address,
  data: "0x",
}).then(console.log);
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I also started a discussion on their Github and then one of their maintainers created an issue for this feature request. Hope it's added soon.
The issue link is [here](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/5374).